# Problem with a try-except clause that makes sure users don't input whitespace strings

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that prompts the user to keep inputting until anything but whitespace is entered. I know I could do it with string comparison but I really want to know why this particular method isn't working.I know it's probably something quite simple but I've been staring at it for too long!

```py
def inputSomething(prompt, errorMessage = 'invalid input - try again'):
    while True:
        value = input(prompt)
        isEmpty = value.isspace() 
        try:          
            isEmpty != True

        except :
            print(errorMessage)
            continue


        return value

isSomething = inputSomething('enter anything: ')
print('x', isSomething)
```

It never throws an exception or prompts the user to input again.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because there is nothing in the `try` block that causes an exception. `isEmpty != True` is a valid logical operation, but it does nothing with the result. You can simply use an `if` condition with whatever validation you want on that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `except` block triggers only when a line of code inside the `try` block raises an exception. Usually, this approach for repeated user input is used when the parsing itself fails leading to a `ValueError`, such as with integers for example.

In your case, the input is a string and hence there are no exceptions thrown. You only need to validate it according to your conditions. Hence, an `if-else` block is appropriate.

The following should work:

```
def inputSomething(prompt, errorMessage = 'invalid input - try again'):
    while True:
        value = input(prompt)
        if value.isspace():
            print(errorMessage)
            continue

        return value
```

Comment: it's `except` not `catch`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the 'catch' @VasuDeo.S :p